# Set radio button onclick two destinations (submit form and redirect)

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button, forms

How is this possible? I have this code to work on half of my needs. It redirects the user when the radio button is clicked but the form is either not saved or submitted to me via email. Is it possible to make it execute 2 commands at a time? Here's the code

```html
<input type="radio" id="display_al" name="display_al" value="display_al" onClick="this.form.action='book-now-2';this.form.submit;"  onMouseOver="style.cursor='hand'">
```

What am I missing here? I am using this for a contact form btw just so people will have ideas. I'm redirecting them whenever they choose another form of payment. I would like to redirect them to a more secure page upon paying with credit card.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and all the fuss. Submit and redirect. Somehow I manage to make it redirect to another page I want but is there any way to save the details they filled up so they wont fill up the form again? That's the one thing I'm missing now

Comment: if you're redirecting by changing `action` of your form and submitting it - you surely have a possibility to get the value with `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending on your forms `method`) or $_REQUEST, the only condition is to put all `<input>`, `<select>`, etc. elements inside your `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:
1) Add some hidden information to the form that tells your form submission script that it needs to redirect to a different page after it saves the info:

First add a hidden field to your form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" id="redirect" />
```

Then change the onclick

```
onclick="document.getElementById('redirect').value='altpayment';this.form.submit;"
```

And update your form handler

```
<?php
//your normal form submission code, and then...

if(isset($_POST['redirect']) && $_POST['redirect'] == "altpayment"){
    header("location: http://www.yoursite.com/book-now-2");
}else{
    //whatever you normally do after submitting the form
}
```

2) Use AJAX to submit the form and then redirect:

create a javascript function

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
 $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.replace("http://www.yoursite.com/book-now-2");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

change the onclick

```
onclick="submitForm();"
```

If you go the second route, be sure to include the JQuery framework on your page and replace `#myForm` with the ID of your form.

Comment: One more quick question though -- where should I place that final code? On the form source itself? I'm not that much of a code savvy..

Comment: the `<script>` block is best added to the `<head>` region of your page, though it can actually go anywhere. Note that I haven't tested the code above, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: you also have to include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` in your head to make it work, also notice, that `serialize()` returns a query string, not a json object